# Keep getting crash in my Swift code

Tags: ios, swift

Error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView2: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        ScrollView.contentSize.height = 5000
        ScrollView.contentSize.width = 375

        ScrollView2.contentSize.height = 1000
        ScrollView2.contentSize.width = 375
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I need help on this:

```
ScrollView2.contentSize.height = 1000
ScrollView2.contentSize.width = 375
```

That's where it highlights the error.

Comment: Have you checked your `@IBOutlets`?

Comment: Unrelated but keep in mind that standard naming conventions dictate that method and variable (and property) names should be begin with lowercase letters and class names begin with uppercase letters.

Comment: What do you mean by that, I have listed them

Comment: In the Interface Builder, link your UI elements to the corresponding `@IBOutlets`. There has to be a gif showing how to do it. This question is asked all the time.

Comment: i have done that ,  @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView2: UIScrollView!

Comment: You have to do a control - drag

Comment: You connected them from the `Storyboard` to the variable? Are they still valid? Did you rename any variable after connecting them? You can click the yellow button above the `ViewController` and check the outlets.

Comment: in your storyboard, select your scroll view, there's a button on the right that looks like a circle with a -> inside. click on that, and make sure where it says referencing outlets, it's actually connected to your IBOutlet var

Comment: inside mainstoryboard i control - drag the Scrollview2 to my ViewController.swift as an outlet, i did the same steps for my first ScrollView but the ScrollView2 gives errors

Comment: What's the actual (English, human readable) error message shown in the debugger console?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Yeah, that's the message when you hit run, but you said there was an error when you did the drag.....

Comment: how can i take a screenshot of this so you can know whats going on

Comment: theres a error highlighted and it says Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)   theres no error when i control - drag

Comment: can you verify that your scroll view in the story board, (when selected and then go to the connections inspector "that circle with the ->" button, is indeed connected to "@IBOutlet weak var ScrollView2: UIScrollView!" under referencing outlets)

Comment: When I click on the connections inspector , in the reference outlets it says ScrollView2-ViewController

Comment: The error is clear - `ScrollView2` is `nil`. This means you didn't connect anything to this outlet.

Comment: try moving those lines to viewWillAppear, I think @rmaddy was right, but just try it. I think I had some IBOutlet being nil under viewDidLoad some time ago, but I'm not in a position to check what exactly it was all about

Comment: How do I move it under viewWillApear, its not in the ViewController.swift file

Comment: You have to add viewWillAppear yourself(just start typing and autocomplete will help you). I dont think it's the problem though, most likely your IBOutlet isn't connected properly....

Comment: maybe i sshould delete the     @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView2: UIScrollView!   and do it again, can you tell me what  to do so i can see if i made a mistake

Comment: why dont you delete the the referencing outlet from the connections inspector, then redo the connection again.

Comment: Have your storyboard open, then click on split view, so you can see the swift file too. Select scroll view 2 on story board and click on connections inspector. from there delete what you've got under referencing outlets. then from new referencing outlets, click and hold onto the + circle, drag over so that it's above @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView2: UIScrollView!, then release your mouse button.... that should do it

Comment: when i put Scrollview2.contentSize.height = 1000 it says the 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
'          Everything else you told me to do is correct but that is the error i keeps getting, i have 3 viewcontroller in storyboard and the first viewcontroller dosent have uiscrollview. the second one does and it dosent get error and the last viewcontroller has uiscrollview 2 which is the problem right now. and all 3 of viewcontrollers are under the class of viewcontroller.swift

Comment: Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration. Turn off this constraint in the current configuration.
I have this as an issue too,  this could help you figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if (ScrollView2 != nil){
    ScrollView2.contentSize.height = 5000
    ScrollView2.contentSize.width = 375
    }


    if (ScrollView != nil){
    ScrollView.contentSize.height = 5000
    ScrollView.contentSize.width = 375

    }
```

thats how you do it just figured it out

Comment: You can always use it as an optional assignment with `scrollView2?.contentSize.height = 5000` for example instead of the nil check. However, if you're using it as an implicitly unwrapped IBOutlet, it should already be non-nil by the time you use it.